# c# interop excel - copy filtered range to array/list

Tags: c#, com-interop, excel-interop

I want to copy filtered Excel Range (particular column) to array or list. My problem is, I'm able to copy an normal range to array easily. But when I apply filter, I'm unable to copy it properly. I have tried multiple ways.

I have tried with `Range.Cells.Value` and `Range.Rows.Cast<Excel.Range>()`. it gives me only two rows(1st two) but there are 15 rows in excel sheet when I filter based on a criteria:

```
    Excel.Range srcRange = sheet.UsedRange;
    srcRange.AutoFilter(field, criteria, Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, Type.Missing, true);
    Excel.Range filteredRange = sheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing); 

    Excel.Range rn = filteredRange.Columns[columnNumber];
    //var myVal = (System.Array)rn.Rows.Cast<Excel.Range>().SelectMany(x => x.ToString());
    //var myVal = (System.Array)rn.Rows.Cast<object>().SelectMany(x => x.ToString()); //this gives exception - com object cannot be casted to string type
    var myVl = (System.Array)rn.Cells.Value;
    arr1 = myVl.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
```

It skips other rows and takes only first continuous rows! So if I have rows indexed 1,2,3 in the filtered criteria, the array is populated only with first three rows. Though there are rows at different index like. I know I can do this something like this:

```
foreach (Excel.Range area in filteredRange.Areas)
       {
           foreach (Excel.Range row in area.Rows)
           {
               int index = row.Row; 
               string test = sheet.Cells[index, column].Value.ToString(); 
               tmpList.Add(test);
           }
       }
```

But this is not a solution for me as I can't write this when I want to copy values from multiple columns! So I was looking for a 1 liner. I don't mind whether I store the values into an array or list.

It would be really helpful if someone can point me into the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
Excel.Range filteredRange = sheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);

            foreach (Excel.Range area in filteredRange.Areas)
            {
                foreach (Excel.Range row in area.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (Excel.Range column in area.Columns)
                    {
                        list.Add(sheet.Cells[row.Row, column.Column].Value.ToString());
                    }                       
                }
            }
```